# How can I get Windows to apply its settings?

Tags: windows-vista, troubleshooting, bsod

I have a computer with a major problem; it gives a blue screen when the login screen loads. I've been using [this guide](http://tech.icrontic.com/article/fix-the-0x0000008e-bsod-once-and-for-all/) to troubleshoot the issue, and now I've run into a problem.

I have determined the issue is not bad memory or a bad hard drive. According to the guide, this means the problem is in the OS. I've tried to follow the steps, but Windows (Vista SP1) somehow doesn't remember any changes. On every reboot, the computer is in exactly the same state it was in before. Any changes to system settings or files won't be recorded. As this means I can't check what is causing the problem, I can't fix my PC.

Is there a way to find out what's causing this? Is it just a mode Windows goes into to protect itself, or is it some other problem? Anything to help troubleshoot will be of great help here.

PS. I'm kind of new to this site. If I messed up, please tell me in the comments.

Comment: [Error 8E](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff559271%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) can be caused by a faulty device driver, faulty hardware itself, or a virus, this is one of the more difficult STOP errors to resolve. Can you log into windows at all? Will [Safe Mode load](http://bertk.mvps.org/html/safemodevista.html) successfully? Did you install anything just before the problem started? If you suspect malware [see my post here](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware/157533#157533)

Comment: As stated, I can not log into Windows normally (it gives the bsod on the login screen). I can, however, access the save mode. No changes I make persist in there, though. Currently I don't suspect anything, I've never seen anything like this before.

Answer (score 0):

As you are able to start in the save mode, can you please send us an HTML export of your bsod with [BlueScreenView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/blue_screen_view.html).

I had a similar problem, a device driver was the fault. But in my scenario I was able to deactivate the drivers permanent.